# JSon.Net JObject.FromObject Vs JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I tried looking for the above comparison but couldn't find an answer.

As there are multiple ways to get a JObject (or all child types inheriting from JToken)
eg:

> Method1

.    `JObject.FromObject(obj);`

> Method2

.    `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));`

would Method1 perform better than Method2 ?

My usecase is related to backing up a set of entities into a text file and restoring it back.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should benchmark it in your own environment to find out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is faster:

```
JObject.FromObject(obj);
```

It builds a JObject directly from the object. The other method serializes the object to JSON a JSON string and then parses the JSON to build a JObject.

Documentation: **[JObject.FromObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm)**

Comment: I did some test. As the size of obj increases JObject.FromObject(obj) shows better results. For small objs (jobjects with 20 properties or so with minimal or no nesting), both methods show similar results. Thanks @James. Will use JObject.FromObject wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) and [there](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs), both method use `jsonSerializer`. So it should be the exact same.

Comment: Thanks @Florian for the quick response. As there are multiple ways to do the same job, so wanted to know if there are any hidden implications.

Comment: `JToken.FromObject` never dumps data to string, and uses JTokenWriter instead, so it should be faster than dumping it to the string and back.